# Allowing improves

Tags: word-usage

Is phrase "allowing improves" correct? For example, is the following sentence correct:

Figure 1 shows configuration allowing improves performance.

Comment: No, it isn't, and I'm not sure what you mean by it. Do you mean "allowing [for] _improvements_ in performance"?

Comment: Thank you for your first answer. Your proposition expresses what I wanted to write.

Comment: You can also use: allowing for improved performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't correct.

If the word "allowing" is a gerund or present participle, then "improves" would have to be a plural noun.  However the word "improve" is not used as a noun. It is a verb.

You probably want "allowing improvements"

> The configuration was simplified, allowing improvements to be made to its performance

Your caption, though, doesn't make sense. I think you mean:

> Fig 1 shows the configuration that allows for improvements in performance.

or could it be

> Fig 1 shows that the configuration allows for improved performance.

Comment: My initial goal was not to use the noun "improvements". Is it possible to use the structure "allow + gerund" in this sentence? I mean something like "Fig 1 shows the configuration allows improving performance".

Comment: We would use the noun _improvement_ rather than the gerund _improving_.

Comment: Without knowing the context it is hard to understand what you mean.  Could it be "Fig 1 shows that the configuration allows for improved performance."

Comment: Generally you should not have a "goal to avoid a noun".  This typically results in unnatural expressions.   A native speaker would very rarely think "I want to express this with a particular part of speech".  The choice of a noun over a gerund is a natural consequence of expressing oneself idiomatically.  We don't think about grammar when we are talking!